# Magento2: Duplicated stores - base_url problem

Tags: magento2, base-url, duplicate

1. We have store `Store A` installed in `public_html/magento2` (available under `live.storeAAA.com`)
2. We duplicated `public_html/magento2` ->
   `public_html/magento_copy`
3. So we ended up with 2 folders with exactly the same contents:

`public_html/magento2`
`public_html/magento_copy`

4. Both installations use different DB (also clonned)
5. I set the web server so that url `copy.storeAAA.com` points to newly cloned folder (`public_html/magento_copy`).
6. Then, I changed in cloned DB (the one for `public_html/magento_copy`) all instances of `live.storeAAA.com` to `copy.storeAAA.com`.

Now, if I access `copy.storeAAA.com` it still redirects me to `live.storeAAA.com`.

Please let me know what I'm missing? Is there any other place (apart from the DB) where I have to change the base URL?

Comment: have you checked the URL in database?

Comment: Yes, please see 6) above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted! For those who might face similar problem: clean cache of newly cloned web site before viewing it.